# Check on submit if amount is empty

Tags: swiftui

How can I check the amount from singleMember is it empty, I need to have instances of this:

```
struct SingleMember: View {
    var memberItem: MemberInfo
    @State var amount: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Divider()
            HStack{
                Image("avatar")
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    Text("\(memberItem.firstName ?? "Unknown")")
                        .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size:15))
                    Text("\(memberItem.phoneNumber ?? "Unknown")")
                        .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size:12))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
                        .frame(width:50)
                        .background(.clear)
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                }.font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On Another View I have :

```
ForEach(memberInfo, id:\.self){ item in
    SingleMember(memberItem: item)
}
```

What I want is to check, if SingleItem amount is not empty, and if not to add to array item.id, item.amount, for example.

I had an idea of using @Binding on SingleMember but that doesn't work because that update all TextFields, but I want every instance to have it's own amount.

What can I do?

Comment: Is `memberInfo` a `@State` or something like that in the parent view?

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure does not have `amount` in it but you still need to assign an `amount` for every item of your data instance then you should append the `amount` data to it one way or another.

You could do with additional arrays but it might be much cleaner to simply wrap your value.

```
struct MemberInfoWithAmount {
    let memberInfo: MemberInfo
    var amount: String
}
```

You don't want to change your view so you can create a custom constructor for it. You didn't provide the code but the one with `ForEach` would look something like this:

```
struct MemberInfoScreen: View {
    
    @State private var memberInfo: [MemberInfoWithAmount]
    
    init(memberInfo: [MemberInfo]) {
        self.memberInfo = memberInfo.map { .init(memberInfo: $0, amount: "") }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(memberInfo.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            ZStack {
                SingleMember(memberItem: memberInfo[index].memberInfo,
                             amount: $memberInfo[index].amount)
                if memberInfo[index].amount.isEmpty {
                    Text("This item is empty")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension MemberInfoScreen {
    
    private struct MemberInfoWithAmount {
        let memberInfo: MemberInfo
        var amount: String
    }
    
}
```

And yes, the amount is now a binding in your other view like so:

```
struct SingleMember: View {
    
    var memberItem: MemberInfo
    @Binding var amount: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Divider()
            HStack{
                Image("avatar")
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    Text("\(memberItem.firstName ?? "Unknown")")
                        .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size:15))
                    Text("\(memberItem.phoneNumber ?? "Unknown")")
                        .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size:12))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
                        .frame(width:50)
                        .background(.clear)
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                }.font(.custom("Ubuntu-Regular", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```